# Hiding textview in a listview based on dynamic position

Tags: android, listview

In my listview I have 3 textviews and I want to hide one textview at some positions.
The positions  at which TextView must hide comes at runtime based on some condition.

If I get the indexes I want to hide, in an array and use this logic,then it hides the TextView only for the last index. please help.

```
int []x={1,2,4};
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){


    if(position==x[i]){
        holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: i bet the last TextView's name is time

Comment: why don't you use `if (position == 1 || position == 2 || position == 4)` instead of `for loop`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: cuz I don't know what will be those positions... thats why.

Comment: You are not using `position` variable to select the textviews

Comment: @PedroVaz I want to hide textview in my listview based on some positions.

Comment: Where are u doing this, i mean in which method ? @HarishVats

Comment: `I want to hide one textview at some positions` do you mean position `x,y` on the screen ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal list item's position.

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m in getView

Comment: Your code should work. What is actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
    if(position==x[i]){
        holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

change this to

```
if(position==x[i]){
     holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     break;
 }
else{
    holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

**OR**
 do something like this

```
int []x={1,2,4};
    boolean exists = false;
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
     if(position==x[i]){
        exists = true;
        break;
      }
   }
   if (exists)
      holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   else
     holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: if(position==x[i]){
     holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     break;
 }
else{
    holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

That worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `OR` condition, instead of `for` loop.

```
if (position == 1 || position == 2 || position == 4)
{
    holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**EDIT** --- You can try this way also

```
   int []x={1,2,3,4};
    boolean hideMe ;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
      hideMe = false;
     if(position == x[i])
     {
        hideMe = true;
        break;
     }
   }
   if (hideMe)
      holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   else
     holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Michael Shrestha gave the same answer